# How to pass jenkinsfile parameters to a powershell script

Tags: powershell, jenkins

I have a `jenkinsfile`, where I am setting a parameter and wants to use it in another powershell script.

Here is my `jenkinsfile`

```
parameters {
        choice( name: 'DeploymentEnvironment',choices: "None\nDev\nQA\nProd",description: 'Deployment Choice')
    }

stage('Publishing to S3') {
    steps {
        withCredentials() {
            echo "${params.DeploymentEnvironment}"
            powershell(". '.\\packages.ps1' ${params.DeploymentEnvironment}")
        }
    }
}
```

```
echo "${params.DeploymentEnvironment}" = QA
```

My `packages.ps1` script

```
...
Write-Output $DeploymentEnvironment
Write-Output $env.DeploymentEnvironment
Write-Output $env:DeploymentEnvironment
Write-Output ($params.DeploymentEnvironment)
...
```

I am unable to get `DeploymentEnvironment=QA` here in `packages.ps1`. Above every `Write-Output` command is printing nothing.

How can I pass and use `DeploymentEnvironment` variable declared in `Jenkinsfile` in my `packages.ps1` script.

**Thanks.**

Comment: I can't tell you how to pass parameters to powershell script, but I can say - ${params.DeploymentEnvironment}" is not correct. To call params in powershell just call it as env: $DeploymentEnvironment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass your input parameter as an environment parameter to the PowerShell runtime environment, the easiest way to do so is using the [environment directive](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#setting-environment-variables) that is a part of the declarative pipeline syntax, which sets parameters (in addition to [default ones](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#using-environment-variables)) that will be loaded as environments variables to the powershell (or cmd) execution environment.
The `environment` directive can be used in the `pipeline` level or in the `stage` level.
In your case you can use something like:

```
parameters {
    choice( name: 'DeploymentEnvironment',choices: ['None', 'Dev', 'QA', 'Prod' ,description: 'Deployment Choice')
}
stage('Publishing to S3') {
    environment {
        DEPLOYMENT_ENVIRONMENT = "${params.DeploymentEnvironment}"
    }
    steps {
        withCredentials() {
           echo DEPLOYMENT_ENVIRONMENT
           powershell(". '.\\packages.ps1'") 
           // DEPLOYMENT_ENVIRONMENT will be available as an environment parameter to the powershell script
        }
    }
}
```

then in your poweshell script use the `DEPLOYMENT_ENVIRONMENT` parameter.

A different approach will be to modify your powershell script to receive a parameter, and pass the parameter like you are doing now.
Btw, if your are only publishing things to s3 you can use the [Pipeline: AWS Steps](https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-aws/) plugin for this task and avoid the powershell script

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion has worked for me. I am collecting few more files from different folder and putting it all together in a S3 bucket. So I don't think [Pipeline: AWS Steps](https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-aws/) can work straight away for me.